# Saving prompt input into array and reading from it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I started to learn javascript and I need some help.
I need to insert prompt inputs into array and read from it.

```
var array = [
    ["Cat","Black","Awesome"],
        ["Dog","White","Funny"],
        ["Chicken","Brown","Delicious"]
    ];

array.push(prompt("Animal name:"));
array.push(prompt("Animal color:"));
array.push(prompt("Type or something:"));
```

If I do something like that and I want to write it out, the output is:

```
Cat,Black,Awesome
Dog,White,Funny
Chicken,Brown,Delicious
```

And my prompt output is (example):

```
Elephant
Blue
Big
```

How would I insert prompt into array that the output would be as above.

Thank you very much for your answer.
I know it's some basic stuff but I've checked a lot of websites and couldnt find an answer.

Comment: haven't you already done that?? you have already pushed it into the array?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I think OP want's to push to another array inside `array`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. How to do that, and how to read from it?

Answer (score 2):

You are not pushing an array into your first array only value, that's why it does not look the same. You could simply retrieve the prompt value into a first array and then push this array into your other one.

```
var firstArray = [
    ["Cat","Black","Awesome"],
    ["Dog","White","Funny"],
    ["Chicken","Brown","Delicious"]
];

var tempArray = [];

tempArray.push(prompt("Animal name:"));
tempArray.push(prompt("Animal color:"));
tempArray.push(prompt("Type or something:"));   

firstArray.push(tempArray);
```